# Java to Js calls. Is there a time limit after which netscape.javascript.JSException would be raised?

Tags: java, javascript, liveconnect

I am receiving the following exception when calling a JavaScript method from a Java applet using JSObject call mechanism.

```
netscape.javascript.JSException: Unspecified error invoking method or accessing property "handOver"
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.MessagePassingJSObject.newJSException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.MessagePassingJSObject.waitForReply(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.MessagePassingJSObject.call(Unknown Source)
    at Screen.Canvas.Pen.handleCall(Canvas.java:359)
```

The JavaScript method `handOver` contains code which may take longer to execute. Is it possible that this exception is raised since there is a time limit for Java to JavaScript calls ? Is there any way to avoid this time-limit?

Comment: That exception doesn't sound like a timeout issue, more likely that your Java Applet isn't connected to your Javascript instance properly. It's not finding the source at all.

Comment: Check out this page. Might not have answers for you, but might point you in the correct direction. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058815/error-when-calling-javascript-method-from-applet